# Findall pattern usind python re

Tags: python

Thanks in advance
I want to find a certain pattern in re. I tried different combinations and this is where i am at.
Here is the code:

```
import re

txt = "Suggested Profile(s) : Win7SP1x64, Win7SP0x64, Win2008R2SP1x64, Win7SP1x64_24000, Win2008R2x32, Win7x32"

match = re.findall(r"Win.+64", txt)

if match:
    y = match[0]

try:
    profiles = y.split(", ")

    for profile in profiles:
        print(profile)
except Exception:
    print("Error")
```

When I run this, I get the following output:

```
Win7SP1x64
Win7SP0x64
Win2008R2SP1x64
Win7SP1x64
```

which is somewhat correct, but it is not showing the complete output. The last word "Win7SP1x64" is not complete, it is "Win7SP1x64_24000" but in output, it only shows till '64'.
Also, i want script to show the words with have '32' as well, not sure how to implement this.

Comment: Your pattern stops at 64 but you want some data that may or may not follow so don't you think your pattern needs to be changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for some expression like **r"Win[^,]+x[2346][_\d]*"**

```
txt = "Suggested Profile(s) : Win7SP1x64, Win7SP0x64, Win2008R2SP1x64, Win7SP1x64_24000, Win2008R2x32, Win7x32"

match = re.findall(r"Win[^,]+x[2346][_\d]*", txt)
```

The **match** variable will contain:

```
['Win7SP1x64', 'Win7SP0x64', 'Win2008R2SP1x64', 'Win7SP1x64_24000', 'Win2008R2x32', 'Win7x32']
```

Comment: Yes that is what i wanted as output. Thanks alot. Will go through the document again to see the meaning of this expression :)

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) out, if the answer helps you

Answer (score 1):

You need to match the trailing characters after `64` too. The regex you specified is only until `64`

From your solution, you can do it like so:

```
match_64 = re.findall(r"Win\w+64\w*", txt)
```

and for 32

```
match_32 = re.findall(r"Win\w+x32\w*", txt)
```